# Configuring defaultFS when using Azure blob with Hadoop

Tags: azure, hadoop, hdfs, azure-blob-storage

We are trying to use azure blob storage with Hadoop. The issue is that we have to set the fs.defaultFS property in core-site.xml but in our case, we are receiving an error. The file and the error both are given below:

```
    <property>
      <name>fs.AbstractFileSystem.wasb.impl</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.Wasb</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>fs.azure.account.key.OUR_STORAGE_ACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net</name>
      <value>"OUR_KEY"</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
      <value>wasb://blob-hdfs@OUR_STORAGE_ACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net</value>
    </property>
```

Now the error on starting up:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI for NameNode address (check fs.defaultFS): wasb://blob-hdfs@OUR_STORAGE_ACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net is not of scheme 'hdfs'.
```

The jar files of both, `hadoop-azure` and `azure-storage` are a part of classpath

Any help on how to solve this error?

Comment: What command are you running when you get the error? start-dfs?

Comment: No, so this is essentially inside a docker container. So hadoop service starts up right when we start the container and the parsing of core-site.xml fails because of this error. So the service itself is unable to start

Comment: The Docker container still runs a command. I'm curious what it is

Comment: seems your configuration still expect schema of `hdfs://`. So, try to replace the first property by `<name>fs.wasb.impl</name>` and `<value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem</value>`. Tested with Hadoop 2.7.3

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to start a name node, see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cindygross/2015/02/04/understanding-wasb-and-hadoop-storage-in-azure/

With your current setup (WASB), you will get that `Invalid URI for NameNode address`, but you should still be able to access your hdfs normally.

If you can do `hdfs dfs -ls /`, then your WASB config is fine.